# How to DENSE_RANK() by state in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have a log table like this:

```
DEVICE | LOG_TIME             | WORKING | 
"A"       2018-11-25 01:00:00    Y
"A"       2018-11-25 01:02:00    Y
"A"       2018-11-25 01:06:00    Y
"A"       2018-11-25 01:06:30    N
"A"       2018-11-25 01:07:15    N
"A"       2018-11-25 01:07:50    Y
"A"       2018-11-25 01:08:20    Y
"A"       2018-11-25 01:09:20    N
"A"       2018-11-25 01:10:30    N
"A"       2018-11-25 01:11:40    N
"A"       2018-11-25 08:12:30    N
"A"       2018-11-25 08:13:50    Y
```

What i Need to know is:

- if the DEVICE has stopped for more than an hour.
- How many hours did it worked without stopping on each "worked" block?

Thanks in advance

EDITED:

As asked, desired results are:

```
DEVICE | LOG_TIME             | WORKING | BLOCK
"A"       2018-11-25 01:00:00    Y        1
"A"       2018-11-25 01:02:00    Y        1
"A"       2018-11-25 01:06:00    Y        1
"A"       2018-11-25 01:06:30    N        2
"A"       2018-11-25 01:07:15    N        2
"A"       2018-11-25 01:07:50    Y        3
"A"       2018-11-25 01:08:20    Y        3
"A"       2018-11-25 01:09:20    N        4
"A"       2018-11-25 01:10:30    N        4
"A"       2018-11-25 01:11:40    N        4
"A"       2018-11-25 08:12:30    N        4
"A"       2018-11-25 08:13:50    Y        5
```

With that grouping by blocks I can get SUMs of time of worked/stopped hours.

Im working with DENSE_RANK () but I can't get it work like that.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show an example of the desired results based on the sample data?

Comment: Edited done, thanks!